# Variables passed as arguments in functions not triggering reactivity?

Tags: svelte

Example:

```
<script>
    let name = 'world';
    
    function changeName(namearg) {
        namearg = "dude";
    }
    
</script>

<h1>Hello {name}!</h1>

<button on:click={() => changeName(name)}>
    Change name
</button>
```

When "Change name" button is clicked, the name on the h1 DOM element does not change.

But it works when i change the function to one without arguments and instead change the name variable directly in it.

I'm sure i'm missing something basic here, any help is appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your code does not make any sense. What exactly are you trying to achieve? What is your goal when the user clicks on the button?

Comment: When the user clicks on the button, the name variable has to change from 'world' to 'dude', there by updating the Dom. But instead of selecting the name variable directly, I need to be able to pass it as an  argument in the function.

Comment: I'm just trying to find out how to pass a variable into a function as an argument and change the value of that variable inside the function and trigger reactivity for elements that use the said variable

Comment: By assigning a new value to `name` you will trigger all reactive statements that rely on `name`. Try adding `$: console.log(name)` and see for yourself what happens in the console every time you click on the button.

Answer (score 1):

The argument's name is colliding with the declared variable. Below is the fixed code. Since you asked a reusable way to achieve multiple names this [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/756fc8668f39436fb22f5aafd8cd9934?version=3.44.3) might help you.

```html
<script>
    import changeName from "./helper.js"
    let name ="world"
</script>

<h1>Hello {name}!</h1>

<button on:click={() => name=changeName("dude")}>
    Change name
</button>
```

```js
//helper.js
   export default function changeName(namearg) {
        return namearg
    }
```

Comment: But you are still changing the name variable, not the argument in the function. I need to do string = 'dude', and still trigger reactivity

Comment: Why would you want string='dude'? You are passing the declared name to the function. I have edited the answer check again. If nothing is passed to the function then it will be 'dude'.

Comment: I've updated the code in my post to avoid variable name confusion. Ultimately, I want this function to be reusable to change several variables. Eg, let name1 = "John"; let name2 = "Jim"; there are two buttons. Onclick function for first button could be () =>changeName(name1) and second one ()=> changeName(name2);

Comment: My answer is still relevant, I do not get why you are hard coding the "dude" when the argument passed should be the right one.

Comment: I'm just trying to find out how to pass a variable into a function as an argument and change the value of that variable inside the function and trigger reactivity for elements that use the said variable.

Comment: I have edited the solution once more and I have added the REPL example.

Comment: Thank you Shriji. This solution should work!

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to set the global `name` to a new value passed from a variable:

```js
<script>
    let name = 'world';

    
    function changeName(newName) {
        name = newName;
    }    
</script>

<h1>Hello {name}!</h1>

<button on:click={() => changeName('dude')}>
    Change name
</button>
```

Remember than a function parameter is an input. Don't assign values to an input ; instead, assign input values to a global variable, for instance. Also, using the same name for global and local (scoped) variables or function parameters is a bad idea (even though it's technically allowed) that adds confusion and impedes readability.

Comment: Thanks. This helps. But how do I reuse this function to change another variable value, let's say name2.

Comment: Then you either create a new function, or you rethink your global approach and use more structured data. For instance you use an array of `names` and modify the function to also accept an index as a parameter. Or you use an object `names` with keys, and modify the function to also accept a key value as a parameter. The solutions are plentiful, which one you pick is dependant on your use case.

Comment: The code was just for demonstration purposes, my use case is a little more complicated than that.Is it not possible to trigger reactivity without explicitly calling the variable inside the function?

Comment: You trigger reactivity by assigning a new value to the variable(s) that you want to base your reactivity on. That's it, there's no complexity to it.

Comment: If your question is, can you trigger reactivity on `name` without assigning a new value to `name`  then is answer is no. That is the whole point of reactivity - to react to *a change in value*.

Comment: I want to assign a new value to the name variable, but instead of changing it directly, i want to be able to pass name as an argument to a function and assign a new value to that argument inside the function.

Comment: Here's the REPL of my real use case i'm testing - https://svelte.dev/repl/f5b07804ef2b4be0a04edcb586aaade4?version=3.44.3 . The goal is to transition the height of list components when an item inside them is deleted/added.

Comment: Since CSS transition does not work with hieght:auto, I'm trying to dynamically set specific height for the list component based on the height of each child (stored in a writable store). I'm using the setListHeight() function to initially set the height. In this function, i'm calling the store explicitly by name and it works. Is there a way i can instead pass the store name as an argument to this function so that i can use the same function to calculate height of another list, like setListHeight(list1store),  setListHeight(list2store)? Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240541/discussion-between-thomas-hennes-and-sateesh).